# Is it possible to connect to sftp server using client side javascript. Is it secure?

Tags: javascript, security

Is it possible to connect to sftp server and read files using client side javascript. How secured is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect to sftp server and read files using client side javascript.

No. Browsers provide no APIs that would allow an SFTP connection to be made.